# Where is the "download" button on Google Takeout?

Tags: export, google-plus-1, google-takeout

I tried to download some of the stuff from Google Takeout, but after creating the archive, I don't see any download button. The following is a screen shot of the browser window.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should appear below the progress bar, to the right, after the archive is created.

Apparently, it doesn't show if the archive is empty. I get the same result for +1s.

[image]